# Recursive query in SQL Server With All Childs

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have searched on the forum for a problem like that i face as i didn't found one , i start a new topic

I have a table named `SubProduct` with the following structure:

```
ProductCode    | SubProduct    | Unit    
11470060       | 11470060.DSP  |  12    
11470060.DSP   | 11470060.EA   |  12    
12110957       | 12110957.DSP  |  12    
12110957.DSP   | 12110957.EA   |  50
```

I need to get to this result, but I can't reach it:

```
Parent             Child            Unit    
11470060       | 11470060.DSP  |  12    
11470060       | 11470060.EA   |  144 (12 * 12)     
12110957       | 12110957.DSP  |  12    
12110957       | 12110957.EA   |  600 (12 * 50)
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please provide additional information to help with your specific problem.  What have you tried that is not working?  This is not a code-writing service.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't think this is a recursive query, despite the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the parent, which you can do using string operations.  Then you can use a `join` for the multiplication.

The following returns what you want in a slightly different form:

```
with sp as (
      select sp.*,
             left(productcode, charindex('.', productcode + '.') - 1) as parent
      from subproduct sp
     )
select spd.parent, spd.unit * spe.unit,
       spd.subproduct as dsp_subproduct, spe.subproduct as ea_subproduct
from sp spd join
     sp spe
     on spd.parent = spe.parent and
        spd.subproduct like '%.DSP' and
        spe.subproduct like '%.EA';
```

You can get this on separate rows using `apply`:

```
with sp as (
      select sp.*,
             left(productcode, charindex('.', productcode + '.') - 1) as parent
      from subproduct sp
     ) 
select spd.parent, v.subproduct, v.unit
from sp spd join
     sp spe
     on spd.parent = spe.parent and
        spd.subproduct like '%.DSP' and
        spe.subproduct like '%.EA' outer apply
     (values (spd.subproduct, spd.unit), (spe.subproduct, spd.unit * spe.unit) ) v(subproduct, unit);
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/LMYNJV75073) is a rextester demonstrating the solution.

Comment: thank you for your response it's very helpful i took the second part using apply otherwise it's not shown the requested values  the request returns  result like this
11470060 11470060.DSP 144
11470060 11470060.EA 144
otherwise the result should be 
11470060 11470060.DSP   12
11470060 11470060.EA         144
also not all the product_code have 2 child DSP And EA there are one's with only one child EA and they are not returned 
i dont know if i explained it clearly

Comment: @MarouaneJaib . . . That is easily fixed.  I added a rextester showing the solution.  If you have a problem with other data (such as missing children of one type or the other), then ask *another* question with appropriate sample data and explanation.  This answer clearly answers the question that you asked here (and if you approve of the answer, you should accept it).

Comment: Thank's a lot for your help